# Calculating the circle between two quadratic curves

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, tangent-line, bezier-curve

I have two quadratic curves sharing one control point $A$. The control points for the first curve are $A, B, C$ and for the second curve: $A, D, E$.

The two quadratic curves are defined as:

- $P(t) = (t - 1)^2A - 2t(t - 1)B + t^2C$
- $P(u) = (u - 1)^2A - 2u(u - 1)D + u^2E$

[image: An image describing the curves and the circle]

I need to find the $t$ value(s) on the curve $P(t)$ for the input value $r$ which is the radius of the circle that touches the tangent lines of both curves (note that there can be more than one circle that matches the criteria). In other words, I need to find the $t$ value where the offset curves (with offset $r$) of the two curves intersect.

I've got far enough to get the equations for the offset curves and a relation between $u$ and $t$ for the intersection points but I'm having trouble getting some sort of relation between $r$ and $t$, which will help me calculate or approximate the intersection points and the maximum radius of the circle that fits between the curves.

[image: 1. Offsets]

Comment: "I've got far enough to get the equations for the offset curves and a relation between u and t for the intersection points". Can you say more ? Does it involve the two 6th degree offset curves associated with the two quadratic Bezier (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) depending parametrically on the size $d$ of the offset ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I got the two offset curves per quadratic Bezier curve by splitting the Bezier curve into X and Y coordinates and intersecting the normal line from a point at the curve with the circle of radius $r$ (offset size). The resulting equation is in the shape of $x = P_x(t) + M_x(t)$ and $y = P_y(t) + N_y(t)$ ([offset equations for curve 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q8oh.png), the equations for curve 2 are the same with $u$ in place of $t$ and $D$ and $E$ in place of $B$ and $C$). Sorry, I'm not exactly sure if those are 6th degree curves.

Comment: IMHO, having worked on Bezier curves, looking for exact equations for such issues is rarely worth the (huge) effort. There are methods giving very satisfying approximate solutions

Comment: @JeanMarie: and in any case, you will end-up with a high order polynomial equation that requires an approximation method.

Comment: In fact, I think you’ll end up with a polynomial equation of degree 16. Two parabolas can intersect in four points, and near each intersection point, there are 4 tangent circles. Or, looking at it algebraically, the offset of a parabola is a rational curve of degree 4, so intersecting two of these will give you 16 solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**Just a suggestion:**

You can construct the offset curve of one of the Beziers (with offset $2r$) and intersect with the other. To implement this, flatten the two curves and intersect the segments pairwise (do not flatten then offset).

A brute-force solution will take effort $O(nm)$ for $n$ and $m$ segments in the respective polylines, but you can reduce this by plane-sweep techniques (Bentley-Ottmann).